# The 'Passive' connection '<appname>' access to protected services is denied

Tags: ios, iphone, flash, apache-flex, adobe

I'm developing a flex mobile iOS application using air sdk 15.app freezes when it display the webview and start communication between servers.it's works fine when I deploy the application directly to the device through the flash builder.the error occurs when I install the app creating the ipa(installed using iTunes)

```
<Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection '<appname>' access to protected services is denied.
```

I have tried many things like changing ios sdk version and disabling ANE's but not working.

```
    backboardd[28] <Notice>: ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=1.0000
    backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
    SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Enabling lock screen media controls updates for screen turning on.
    SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: [MPUNowPlayingController] Already registered for now playing notifications.
    wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870521.165025]: Device display is ON
    wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870521.165739]: Already connected to gg-spnet-sysdev.
    SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
    backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->6 (deferring until bootloaded)
    backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
    backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 6->6
    kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 1
    kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 1 (set level to 0x240)
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.494937]: 
     wifid[15] <Notice>: Too frequent(0.855288 secs) rssi event from driver, ignoring
     wifid[15] <Notice>: 
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.549667]: ATJManager: setting ask-to-join interaction mode to Interactive
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.550029]: ATJManager: no entries to purge
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.550268]: Device is UNLOCKED
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.550491]: Ignoring lock state
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.550717]: problematic networks =  and potentially problematic networks = 
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.550984]: Unblacklisting
     backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 6->3
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.551516]: No change in Background Scan candidates. Skip re-programming Background Scan
     wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[436870522.553549]: Already connected to <wifispotname>.
     lockdownd[52] <Notice>: 00241000 set_response_error: handle_get_value GetProhibited
     wirelessproxd[67] <Notice>: (Note ) Created WPTransfer Object for touchsetupd with daemon <DaemonBluetooth: 0x16d439b0>

kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[551] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/AEA64AE2-F6EB-48FD-932A-E4EC9EDDCC8E (sandbox)
    backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'appname' access to protected services is denied.
```

Comment: This error is what's known as a "Red Herring".  It's a clue that's misleading. The HID isn't a real error that affects your app.  There should be other messages that may indicate what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I've edited the post and added further logs

Comment: all I can see wifi issues and "access to protected services is denied." when access the servers.is this a kind of security issue?